# CakePHP - how to modify FormHelper and add div after input?

Tags: cakephp

I am trying to modify FormHelper's behaviour to meet my application requirements. I would like to use native FormHelper but for all input I need to add some short message providing help to the user and describing the particular field.

My idea is to create my own helper and pass a help message as an argument. This function will modify form's inputDefaults setting and call a native FormHelper input function.

For example:

```
class MsgFormHelper extends AppHelper {
      public function input($name, $message, $options) {
        $this->_View->Form->_inputDefaults['after'] .= '<div>'.$message.'</div>';
        return $this->_View->Form->input($name, $options);
    }
}
```

But this solution notices this error:

> Notice (8): Indirect modification of overloaded property
>   FormHelper::$_inputDefaults has no effect...

Is there some way how to modify "after" value in form's inputDefaults setting?

Answer (score 0):

I probably found a solution (it works but I am not sure it doesn't violate some CakePHP's principles). Thanks for your opinions.

```
class MsgFormHelper extends AppHelper {

    public function __construct(View $view, $settings = array()) {
        parent::__construct($view, $settings);
    }

    public function input($name, $message, $options) {

        $add_message = true;

        if (isset($options['after'])) {
            $options['after'] = trim($options['after']);
            $add_message = empty($options['after']);
        }

        if ($add_message) {
            $options['after'] = '<div class="input-help">' . $message . '</div>' . $this->_View->Form->_inputDefaults['after'];
        }

        return $this->_View->Form->input($name, $options);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be extending the `FormHelper` itself not `AppHelper`. Then in your controller use the aliasing feature so that you still use `$this->Form->input()` in your views but it would actually refer to your custom helper.

`public $helpers = array('Form' => array('className' => 'MsgForm'))`